# Add something to the java classpath

Tags: java, classpath, addition

I have a jar-File, which I want to add to the classpath, so I ran java -cp ".;C:\Path\to\my\magical\jarfile.jar;.\some\other\directory" MyClass

The Problem is: I use some import-commands in my class, an Java doesn't find them anymore, because I replaced the classpath. I want just add two elements to the Path. How is this posible under Windows?

Comment: are you executing the `java` command from the root directory of the build artifact(s), or are you running the command from within a package-directory?

Comment: *I use some import-commands in my class, an Java doesn't find them anymore* Then one or more of the paths in the classpath is wrong. *DID* you set a classpath *before* you issued that command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
specifies:

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

So, to add to that default, include the CLASSPATH environment variable in your invocation:

```
java -cp ".;C:\Path\to\my\magical\jarfile.jar;.\some\other\directory;%CLASSPATH%"
```

Comment: `.` is already in Michèle’s classpath.

Comment: @VGR. %CLASSPATH% isn't. Which was my answer.